# What does "red-black tree" mean in: TreeSet, which stores its elements in a red-black tree, orders its elements based on their values;

Tags: java, collections, set, treeset

I was reading [Java Tutorial Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) and I have encountered the statement below.

> TreeSet, which stores its elements in a red-black tree, orders its
>   elements based on their values;

I was confused by the phrase "red-black tree", I did a basic web search and did not find satisfactory answer.

Comment: Wikipedia has an entry Red-black_tree. and there were some other pretty good entries just on the first page(google). Curious as to why your search did not go so well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A red–black tree is a kind of self-balancing binary search tree. There are several kinds of self-balancing trees, such as 2-3 trees, AA trees, AVL trees, and Red-black trees.

The purpose of a self balancing tree is evident when you consider the worst case in which a non-self-balancing binary search tree can exist.

Consider this case: Begin by inserting an integer into an empty tree (non-self-balancing). Continue inserting integers with each value greater than the previous. Your worst cast retrieval time would be for the last element inserted with a time complexity of O(n). This is because you have to traverse the entire tree to get to the desired element, much like a linked list.

This is much worse than a balanced binary search tree with a time complexity of O(lg n). Therefore there are methods, such as a red-black tree, which try to ensure the tree is balanced (meaning the weight of each child is the same).

Answer (score 3):

For me the third search result was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree, which nicely explains the concept.

Basically it's a method to keep a binary tree almost balanced, so that independent of the insertion order it does not degenerate into a linked list while also keeping insertion (and removal) cost low.

Answer (score 0):

1) Every node has a color either red or black and Root of the tree is always black.

2) There are no two adjacent red nodes (A red node cannot have a red parent or red child, red need to have black parent).

3) Every path from root to a NIL node has same number of black nodes.